# Powershell Get-ItemProperty Returns data differently depending upon 32 or 64bit OS

Tags: powershell

My first question on this forum so please forgive any mistakes etc.

I'm writing a PowerShell script that needs to run on both 32 and 64 bit OS's. This in itself is not a problem as I can easily identify the two architectures. The problem arises when I issue a "Get-ItemProperty" command on the registry. With a 32 bit OS I get four lines of unwanted data before the data I actually want, ie PSPath, PAParentPath, PSChildName & PSProvider. The same command issues on a 64 bit OS places those same pieces of data after my data. Having written some PS script to "Select-Object -last 1" to get the bit of data from the end of the last line which works perfectly on 32 bit machines I then found that everything was reversed on 64 bit machines and PS script no longer worked. I've tried using "Select-Object First 1" but this only returns the first part of my data line, if I change the value to 2 then I get everything. So, is there a way of either collecting the whole of the first line or stopping "Get-ItemProperty" from returning all the unwanted lines?
I hope all of that makes sense?
Thanks in advance
MrMackyD

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm overlooking something here, but shouldn't

```
 Get-ItemProperty <item> | Select-Object PSPath,PAParentPath,PSChildName,PSProvider
```

work perfectly fine in both cases?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but it is the four "PS" values I want to eradicate, I just want to select my data stored in the registry, I'm not interested in the PS values. Is there a way of NOT selecting these entries or stopping Powershell from retrieving them?

Comment: Sure, that would be

    `Get-ItemProperty <item> | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty PSPath,PAParentPath,PSChildName,PSProvider`

I somehow seem to be too stupid to format the comment properly, (it looks fine in the preview), are there any special tricks for that? ^^

Comment: Whatever,
Your suggestions worked perfectly, thank you very much
Regards MrMackyD

Answer (score 0):

What *is* the data you actually want? Can you simply select that directly? For example, `(gp Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion).DevicePath` reads the `DevicePath` entry directly, ignoring the `PS*` properties added by PowerShell.

Your issue is not so much of bitness, but of ignoring the PowerShell-specific properties.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but unfortunately the Registry name is date and as time goes on these entries grow. The actual data is a "Hotfix" level so as each Hotfix is applied another entry is added to the registry. What has worked with the 32bit version is simply to Select the Last entry and this has worked because the four "PS" values are listed first. With the 64 bit version all of the Hotfix values are listed followed by the four "PS" values. Any ideas ???

Comment: @MrMackyD: it sounds like you want the *latest* entry. Is there any way to sort them (based on name, perhaps?) Because even ignoring the PowerShell properties, `Get-ItemProperty` isn't guaranteed to return them in any particular order, so picking the *last* of these is not a stable solution.